# compare different id's in a column in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a column in a df that has different id's. Some of the id's are duplicated. I am trying to compare the different id's (starting from first) and then see if the same id is present in the next line (row) of the column. If it is the same id then i do something and if not go to the next id and repeat the same. Here is the column in the df

```
     V4
Contig1401|m.3412
Contig1428|m.3512
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1757|m.4476
Contig1598|m.4011
Contig1759|m.4481
Contig1685|m.4244
```

As you can see that there are id's that are duplicated and some are not. How do i go about it? So far i have written this.....

```
first_id <- "Contig1401|m.3412"

    for (i in data$V4) {
      if (i=first_id) {
        do something.....
      } else {
        do something.
      }
    }
```

But i don't understand ho will i go after this. Basically i want to obtain this

```
       V4          V5
Contig1401|m.3412  1
Contig1428|m.3512  1
Contig1755|m.4465  2
Contig1755|m.4465  
Contig1897|m.4878  2
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1757|m.4476  1
Contig1598|m.4011  1
Contig1759|m.4481  1
Contig1685|m.4244  1
```

Any ideas of how i can do this?

Thanks
Upendra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this do what you want but this produces your final table

```
df <- read.table(text="Contig1401|m.3412
Contig1428|m.3512
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1757|m.4476
Contig1598|m.4011
Contig1759|m.4481
Contig1685|m.4244",header=F,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# One way
df$id <- duplicated(df$V1 , fromLast=T) + 1 
df$id[duplicated(df$V1) ] <- NA

#or
df$id <- rep(rle(df$V1)$lengths,rle(df$V1)$lengths)
df$id[duplicated(df$V1) ] <- NA
```

Comment: You might need to add `as.character(df$V1)` to make sure the `rle` call works.

Comment: Thanks - im always forgetting my .Rprofile default of stringsAsFactors=F

Comment: Both works but second one is better since it doesn't depend number of duplicate id's. For instance in some cases i have more than 2 id's that are duplicated and first method needs modifying every time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

```
dat <- read.table(text="V4
Contig1401|m.3412
Contig1428|m.3512
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1757|m.4476
Contig1598|m.4011
Contig1759|m.4481",header=T)

# Find entries where the next entry is the same
# Convert TRUE values to be 2 and FALSE values to be 1 by adding +1
same.as.next <- sapply(1:length(dat[,1]),
                function(x)identical(dat[x,],dat[(x+1),]))+1

dat <- data.frame(dat,V5 = same.as.next)

dat[duplicated(dat$V4),]$V5 <- NA
```

#### Edit to address OP's comment regarding entries that show up > 2 times

```
# notice Contig1755|m.4465 shows up 5 times in this example
dat.multduplicates <- read.table(text="V4
Contig1401|m.3412
Contig1428|m.3512
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1897|m.4878
Contig1757|m.4476
Contig1598|m.4011
Contig1759|m.4481
Contig1755|m.4465
Contig1755|m.4465",header=T)

# same as before
same.as.next <- sapply(1:length(dat.multduplicates[,1]),
            function(x)identical(dat.multduplicates[x,],dat.multduplicates[(x+1),]))+1
dat.multduplicates <- data.frame(dat.multduplicates,V5 = same.as.next)

# this approach should handle the duplicates
dat.multduplicates[which(dat.multduplicates$V5==2)+1,]$V5 <- NA
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there are more than 2 duplicate id's in the column. I guess i can add one more of this dat[(x+2)] but what if there are more than 3. Is there a way around?

Comment: @upendra see my edit.  I think that should clear up the problem of > 2 duplicates for an id.